# How to programmatically run all test cases forever?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng, appium

How to programmatically run all test cases forever ? Below is the setup I have … now I have to run this code infinitely …another requirement is I need to restart the app again after @aftersuite… I need to tear down the test cases because I need to produce report after each aftersuite …

For example :

```
public class SimpleTest extends TestBase
{
    AppiumDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

       // DesiredCapabilities and all setup
    }
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void testcase1()throws InterruptedException {
        login();
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void testcase2() throws InterruptedException {
        //something
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void testcase3() throws InterruptedException {
      //something
    }

    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void testcase4 throws InterruptedException {
     //something
    }

    @Test(priority = 5)
    public void testcase() throws InterruptedException{
      //something
    }

    @Test(priority = 6)
    public void testcase6() throws InterruptedException{
     //something
    }

    @Test(priority = 7)
    public void testcase_logout() throws InterruptedException {
        logout();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void testCaseTearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: ...use an infinite loop?

Comment: can u suggest me by code ? Above is my setup configuration.

Comment: Call the run() method in testng  class in an infinite loop. Refer to the example in the doc - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Create another class that would call these tests...

```
public SimpleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         while (true) {
             org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main("SimpleTest");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Line with JUnitCore in the code now will call the tests. You can put that in the main like in the example or put it in a loop inside a method with a @Before tag so it gets called first or where ever you need it to be called. Hope this helps.

Comment: i didn't get what u mean .. how can i use this in @BeforeSuite method  ?

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your tests in testNG.xml .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Regression suite" verbose="1" >
  <test name="SampleTests" >
    <classes>
      <class name="com.first.example.SampleTest"/>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Then programmatically run them with TestNG object.

```
import org.testng.TestNG;

import java.util.List;

public class RunTestNGXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
        suites.add("testng.xml");
        testng.setTestSuites(suites);
        String outputDir ="src"+File.separator+"reports";
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");

        while(true){
        testng.setOutputDirectory(outputDir+File.separator+formater.format(calendar.getTime()));
        testng.run();
         }
    }
}
```

The caveat with infinite loop is that your emailable-report would be overwritten in each iteration. So configure the test-output directory path with timestamps. Otherwise log4j appender can easily do the job of continuous logging.